How to remove multiple DOM elements using a single function in JavaScript?
I'm working on a project where I need to remove multiple DOM elements from the page. Sometimes I need to remove a single element, and other times I need to remove a collection of elements (like a NodeList or an HTMLCollection). To streamline my code, I want to write a single function that can handle both cases.
I came up with the following function:
function removeElement(element) {
    if (element instanceof NodeList || element instanceof HTMLCollection) {
        // If the element is a NodeList or HTMLCollection, iterate over its elements and remove each one
        element.forEach(e => e.remove());
    } else {
        // Otherwise, assume it's a single DOM element and directly call remove() on it
        element.remove();
    }
}


I tried writing a function that can handle the removal of both single DOM elements and collections of elements (NodeList or HTMLCollection). Here's the function I came up with:
javascript
function removeElement(element) {
    if (element instanceof NodeList || element instanceof HTMLCollection) {
        // If the element is a NodeList or HTMLCollection, iterate over its elements and remove each one
        element.forEach(e => e.remove());
    } else {
        // Otherwise, assume it's a single DOM element and directly call remove() on it
        element.remove();
    }
}


I expected this function to be versatile enough to handle different scenarios in my project where I need to remove elements from the DOM. Specifically, I wanted a single function that would work whether I was dealing with a single element or multiple elements.
Example Usage:
// Removing a single element
const singleElement = document.querySelector('#singleElement');
removeElement(singleElement);

// Removing multiple elements
const multipleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.multipleElements');
removeElement(multipleElements);



what issue are you having with the function?

i want to know that if there is already built in function for dom that we use only remove element function for single and multiple elemet without itret

no, there is not, and your function will fail too

Notice, that HTMLCollection doesn't contain forEach method.

An HTMLCollection and a NodeList both implement an array-like interface, while an element does not.
You can use this knowledge to discriminate the type of value in order to iterate and remove items in the collection — or remove the single element. Below is an example which follows the advice from MDN when iterating:

An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed. For this reason it is a good idea to make a copy (e.g., using Array.from) to iterate over if adding, moving, or removing nodes.
— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

The function remove below:

returns early in case of a falsy value (e.g. a null result from the querySelector API), otherwise…
in the case that the value has a property length it is expected to be array-like, and the items are collected into a static array before being iterated over for removal, otherwise…
the value's remove method is invoked

You can select the "Run code snippet" button to reload the demo in order to try the buttons in different orders.


function remove(removable) {
  if (!removable) return;
  if ("length" in removable) {
    for (const element of Array.from(removable)) element.remove();
  } else removable.remove();
}

// Removing a single element
document.getElementById("removeSingle").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const singleElement = document.querySelector("#singleElement");
  remove(singleElement);
});

// Removing multiple elements
document.getElementById("removeMultipleNL").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".multipleElements");
  remove(nodeList);
});

document.getElementById("removeMultipleHC").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("multipleElements");
  remove(htmlCollection);
});
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
#singleElement { color: red; }
.multipleElements { color: blue; }
<div>
  <button id="removeSingle">Remove single</button>
  <button id="removeMultipleNL">Remove multiple as NodeList</button>
  <button id="removeMultipleHC">Remove multiple as HTMLCollection</button>
  <div id="singleElement">single</div>
  <div class="multipleElements">multiple</div>
  <div class="multipleElements">multiple</div>
</div>



Code in the TypeScript Playground
